# Accessing Rails variable in CoffeeScript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I want to use the current user's through my coffee script. But if I try to use `current_user` in my CoffeeScript, I get the undefined variable current_user in console of browser.

Is there any way to access it in coffee script? What I exactly wish to do is as follows:

```
current_user.updated_at < Date.now().getTime()
```

I need it to implement this in my Rails app.

Comment: You could try looking at this gem https://github.com/gazay/gon. I haven't used it myself but others have recommended it here occasionally.

Comment: What's that codeline? :O I really don't get it what you want to do.. On the left side there's ruby code and on the right there's Javascript?! ლ(ಠ益ಠლ)

Answer (score 2):

For raw javascript + erb

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var my_foo = <%= some_ruby_expression %>
</script>
```

e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var user_name = "<%= current_user.name %>";
</script>
```

except `var` keyword, this is a valid coffeescript code, I believe.

Btw, is it really what you are asking for? - I don't know -))

**UPDATE**

`current_user` is a ruby/active_record object. You might assign it to a javascript variable, but can't use as you did in ruby.

But below snippet might give you some idea. I've created a rails project, and scaffolded a page model.

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @page.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Email:</strong>
  <%= @page.email %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Comments:</strong>
  <%= @page.comments %>
</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var mypage = '<%= raw @page.to_json %>'; // attention to single quotes
    console.log(mypage);
</script>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_page_path(@page) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', pages_path %>
```

Then you can parse and use it as an ordinary javascript object. Below picture show, how I did it.

[image]

**UPDATE #2**

do it in coffeescript file.

```
window.onload = ->
  myvar = '<%= raw @page.to_json %>'
  myvarAsObj = JSON.parse(myvar)
  do_something_with myvarAsObj
  return
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want to use `current_user` which is a helper's variable provided by devise gem.

Comment: @siegyy22 Not working. But anyhow even to make this work, I have to write it in that page itself. But i wish to write it on .coffee.erb file. Do you have any idea regarding it? Thanks :)

Comment: @siegy22 Yes i saw your answer. But i haven't run the app in production mode.

Comment: @Vishal join the chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133797/current-user-in-javascript

Comment: @marmeladze Thanks for your effort, but i need to access those in coffee script file that is under app/assets/javascript folder. (i.e. in asset pipeline).

Comment: it's enough easy to implement. i'm updating my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Coffee script is turned into javascript and runs on the browser.  What you want to do is render current_user.updated_at into a node in HTML, then use coffee script to extract that value.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but is it possible with any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript files are (more or less) static files which will be executed by the browser. I don't know if you ever deployed an rails app in production. You'll run the command `bin/rake assets:precompile` which will generate one (or more) massive javascript file(s). So how would you find out the current user at this time? there's no HTTP request at all, so how could there be a user?

So to do this, you could either write the current user to a HTML node and then read it again with javascript (coffeescript) (**which in my opinion is the best way**) or you could print a script tag into your view containing what you want from your user.